# EFCore ValueObject not marking Parent as changed?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design

Hello I have an entity 'Person'. With an 'Alias' Value object

Person

```
 public partial class Person : BaseEntity, IAggregateRoot
{
  public Alias Alias { get; set; }
  //..other properties...

}
```

PersonConfiguration.cs

```
entity.OwnsOne(o => o.Alias, a =>
{
   a.WithOwner(x=>x.Person);
});
```

Alias

```
public class Alias :ValueObject
{
 public string FirstName { get; private set; }
 public string MiddleName { get; private set; }
 public string LastName { get; private set; }
}
```

If I make a change to a property on Alias - Change FirstName -  it does not mark that Person as changed in the change tracker. I've got my auditing being done with the change tracker. So the last update date and user are not being set if I just change a property on the Alias.

Is there something I can do to fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: You also need to have a case for when `EntityState.Unchanged`. Then perform a check to see if the entry has **owned entities**. If it does update that auditable properties.

Comment: Any example on how to check if an entry has owned entities? I see a way to check if an entity is owned.

Comment: you can use `entry.References.Any(r => r.TargetEntry.MetaData.IsOwned() && r.TargetEntry.State == EntityState.Added && r.TargetEntry.State == EntityState.Modified)`

Answer (score 1):

Create an EntityEntry extension

```cs
public static bool HasChangedOwnedEntities(this EntityEntry entry)
   => entry.References.Any(r => r.TargetEntry != null &&
      r.TargetEntry.MetaData.IsOwned() && 
      r.TargetEntry.State == EntityState.Added && 
      r.TargetEntry.State == EntityState.Modified)
```

Then call it in the case for `EntityState.Unchanged`

```cs
if (entry.HasChangedOwnedEntities())
{
   entry.Entity.LastModidfiedBy = userId;
   entry.Entity.LastModidfied = _datetime.Now;
}
```

Comment: This works, but fails when the owned entity is deleted (null'ed) since TargetEntry will be null then

Answer (score 0):

Found a way -  Not thrilled about it but it works..

```
var ownedEntries = _context.ChangeTracker.Entries<ValueObject>().Where(f => f.Metadata.IsOwned() && f.State == EntityState.Modified).ToList();
foreach (var item in ownedEntries)
{
    var ownedNavigations = item.Metadata.GetNavigations().Where(n => n.ForeignKey.IsRequiredDependent).ToList();
    foreach (var nav in ownedNavigations)
    {
        var ownerEntry = item.Reference(nav.Name).TargetEntry;
        if (ownerEntry != null)
        {
            // Get the owner entity using reflection
            var ownerEntity = ownerEntry.Entity
            // Set the owner entity as modified
            var ownerEntryType = ownerEntry.GetType();
            var stateProperty = ownerEntryType.GetProperty("State", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            stateProperty?.SetValue(ownerEntry, EntityState.Modified);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Value objects should be immutable.  You're not supposed to change the properties of a value object after it has been created.

Don't change a property of Alias, replace it.

**Person**

```
Person.Alias = new Alias("John", "Robert", "Smith");
// Change name
Person.Alias = Person.Alias.ChangeFirstName("Dave");
```

**Alias** (immutability enforced by using `init` setter)

```
public string FirstName { get; init; }
public string MiddleName { get; init; }
public string Surname { get; init; }

public Alias(string firstName, string middleName, string surname)
{
    FirstName = firstName;
    MiddleName = middleName;
    Surname = surname;
}

public Alias ChangeFirstName(string newFirstName) =>
    new Alias(newFirstName, MiddleName, Surname);
```

Comment: That is what we are doing. But the person is still 'modified' so we need to be able to track it. Currently if I replace the alias and save, Person is not being detected as being changed.

Comment: In your OP you said "If I make a change to a property on Alias".  That's not the same as what I'm proposing.  In my code above I do not change a property on Alias.  I replace the Alias object on Person with a completely new instance.  That would prompt EF Change Tracker to detect the change on Person.

Comment: @NeilW: `Alias` is an owned property as you can see in the `PersonConfiguration.cs`. Owned properties don't have an explicit id and are treated as columsn of the same table as `Person` (the column will be translated to column names by appending the property name as prefix, i.e. `Alias.FirstName`maps to `AliasFirstName` property on `Users` table